# Desktop application, dependency injection

Tags: design, dependency-injection, user-interface, service-locator

I am thinking of applying a real dependency injection library to my toy C#/GTK# desktop application. I chose [NInject](http://www.ninject.org/), but I think this is irrelevant to my question.

There is a database object, a main window and several utility window classes. It's clear that I can inject the database into every window object, so here DI is useful. But does it make sense to inject utility window classes into other window classes?

Example: I have classes such as:

```
class MainWindow {…}
class AddItemWindow {…}
class AddAttachmentWindow {…}
class BrowseItemsWindow {…}
class QueryBuilderWindow {…}
class QueryBrowserWindow {…}
class PreferencesWindow {…}
…
```

Each of the utility classes can be opened from MainWindow. Some utility windows can also be opened from other utility windows. Generally, there might be a really complex graph of who can open whom. So each of those classes might need quite a lot of other window classes injected. I'm worried that such usage will go against the suggestion not to inject too many classes at once and become a code smell. Should I use some kind of a service locator object here?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a `UtilityWindowOpener` class. Its methods will open the various utility windows. Then you can just inject a `UtilityWindowOpener` anywhere you may need to open a utility window. The `UtilityWindowOpener` will then have the various utility windows injected (or possibly create them on demand, that's hidden behind the interface). It'll also bring all navigation logic into fewer locations.

Comment: So, a kind of service locator which would get its dependencies from DI framework?

Comment: @liori, I'd distinguish it from the service locator because it wouldn't return the utility windows. It would open the utility windows based on the methods called.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overinjection instead of injecting all Window's objects of classes *Window into `MainWindow` you could use [`Ninject.Extension.Factory`](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki). In this case *Abstract Factory* could has following interface:

```
public interface IWindowFactory
{
    AddItemWindow CreateAddItemWindow();
    AddAttachmentWindow CreateAddAttachmentWindow();
    /* etc */
}
```

And then add *binding* to `Load` implementation of `Ninject.NinjectModule`:

```
Bind<AddItemWindow>()
    .ToSelf()
    .NamedLikeFactoryMethod<AddItemWindow, IWindowFactory>(f => f.CreateIWindowFactory());

Bind<AddAttachmentWindow>()
    .ToSelf()
    .NamedLikeFactoryMethod<AddItemWindow, IWindowFactory>(f => f.CreateIWindowFactory());

/* etc */

// and factory binding
Bind<IWindowFactory>()
    .ToFactory()
    .InSingletonScope();
```

Two additional points:

- There is an excelent article by Mark Seemann [Pattern Recognition: Abstract Factory or Service Locator?](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/01/PatternRecognitionAbstractFactoryOrServiceLocator.aspx) — so this solution is ok, if you care about *Serice Locator* anti-pattern, and …
- To make it 100% not the *Serice Locator* anti-pattern make sure that *Abstract Factory* creates only Windows objects, not everything.

Comment: According to the mentioned article _Pattern Recognition: Abstract Factory or Service Locator_ you have just created a _Service Locator_.